# LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate and kotlin suspendCoroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, locationmanager

I want to get the current GPS location of the device using `LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate()`. The following code is used to wrap the call to LocationManager in a kotlin suspending function:

```kotlin
private var locationManager =
        context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

@RequiresPermission("android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
suspend fun getCurrentLocationPreS(): Coordinate? = suspendCoroutine {
    val handlerThread = HandlerThread("getCurrentLocation() HandlerThread")
    handlerThread.start()

    try {
        // Use of deprecated function is ok because we are pre android S
        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            { location ->
                handlerThread.quit()
                it.resume(
                    Coordinate(
                        location.latitude,
                        location.longitude
                    )
                )
            },
            handlerThread.looper
        )
    }
    catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
        it.resumeWithException(ex)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use `suspendCoroutine` to make the asynchronous location call. This implementation works for some devices but I have problems on other devices. Sometimes the supending function never returns and waits forever because the location update callback is not called. The app also has the needed permissions and GPS is enabled.

What edge case leads to a state that the function never returns?

Logcat does not indicate any exception or other error. The app also does not crash. The only symptom is that the `getCurrentLocationPreS()` never returns.

Comment: Maybe GPS is unavailable or disabled on these devices, and since you're requesting GPS specifically instead of a fused provider, you don't get a response. Requesting a single GPS update is probably not very useful. The first response back from GPS is often way off because it takes a few seconds to stabilize if it hasn't been used recently. Also, you don't need to create a special thread to handle your callback, since all you're doing in the callback is calling the Coordinate constructor one time, which is trivial to do on any thread. So I would just omit the Looper parameter.

Comment: Before I call this function I ensured that GPS is enabled and the device where I have this issue is a Samsung Galaxy S8 which should have GPS functionality. The location being a few meters off is no problem, I only need a rough but up to date estimation.

Comment: maybe `handlerThread.looper` blocks the function and it never returns. Try to remove this line and see if it works. I don't see any reason to use a `HandlerThread` here.

Answer (score 1):

Just because GPS is enabled doesn't mean that it is working  properly. You might have a poor signal when being indoors or in areas packed with tall buildings. If you look at the implementation of `requestSingleUpdate` you will see it uses a timeout of 30s, so if the timeout expires, your callback will never be executed and your coroutine gets stuck indefinitely.

I would suggest to either to use a timeout for this call as well or consider using `FusedLocationProviderClient` which allows you to get the last known location in a safer way.

I would also suggest using `Looper.getMainLooper()`, the runtime overhead from temporarily switching to the main thread is negligible compared to the effort of making sure you are properly managing the `HandlerThread`

So my take on this would look something like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun getCurrentLocationPreS(): Coordinate? = withTimeoutOrNull(30.seconds){
    suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        try {
            // Use of deprecated function is ok because we are pre android S
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                { location ->
                    cont.resume(
                        Coordinate(
                            location.latitude,
                            location.longitude
                        )
                    )
                },
                Looper.getMainLooper()
            )
        }
        catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            cont.resumeWithException(ex)
        }
    }
}
```